# Deleting folders across directories

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a directory structure like this:

... / firstlevel / output / sub-(101-162) / ...

In each sub-XXX folder, I have the folders run_1, run_1.feat, run_1+.feat, run_1++.feat, run_2, run_2.feat, run_2+.feat run_2++.feat.

Is there a one-line command I can run to keep only the run_1++.feat and run_2++.feat folders for all sub-XXX folders?

In other words, for each sub-XXX folder, I want to keep the folders run_1++.feat and run_2++.feat and delete run_1, run_1.feat, run_1+.feat, run_2, run_2.feat, run_2+.feat.

Thanks!

Comment: [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is **called** "find", but you should really think of it as "act on files or directories". Familiarize yourself with this tool, it's really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible interpretations of your question depending whether you want to delete a sub-directory that would be named `firstlevel/output/sub-101/foo/`, or not.

###### Positive interpretation

If you want to delete all sub-directories named `run_1`, `run_1.feat`, `run_1.+feat`, `run_2`, `run_2.feat` or `run_2.+feat` (but keep `firstlevel/output/sub-101/foo/`), you can try:

```
ls firstlevel/output/sub-{101..162}/run_{1,2}{,{,+}.feat}/
```

If the list looks correct replace `ls` with `rm -rf`. Note: the trailing `/` prevents deletion of regular files, only directories will match. It could be that the list of directories to delete is too long and that you get an `Argument list too long` error. In this case you can try `find`:

```
find firstlevel/output/sub-{101..162} -maxdepth 1 -type d \
\( -name run_[12] -o -name run_[12].feat -o -name run_[12]+.feat \) -print
```

When convinced replace `-print` with `-delete`. If the argument list is still too long try to split the `101..162` range in several smaller ones:

```
find firstlevel/output/sub-{101..131} -maxdepth 1 -type d \
\( -name run_[12] -o -name run_[12].feat -o -name run_[12]+.feat \) -print
find firstlevel/output/sub-{132..162} -maxdepth 1 -type d \
\( -name run_[12] -o -name run_[12].feat -o -name run_[12]+.feat \) -print
```

###### Negative interpretation

If you want to delete all sub-directories **not** named `run_1++.feat` or `run_2++.feat` (including `firstlevel/output/sub-101/foo/`), you can try:

```
( shopt -s extglob; ls firstlevel/output/sub-{101..162}/!(run_[12]++.feat)/ )
```

The `extglob` option enables extended pattern matching operators, like `!(pattern)` that match anything except `pattern`. Running the list of commands in a subshell (the surrounding parentheses) limits the scope of  `extglob`. Again, if the list looks correct replace `ls` with `rm -rf`. And again, if the list is too long you can try `find`:

```
find firstlevel/output/sub-{101..162} -maxdepth 1 -type d \
! -name run_[12]++.feat -print
```

When convinced replace `-print` with `-delete`.